# y-intercept of a line that passes through any two points on the curve of a polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

Given a polynomial $P\left ( x \right )= a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{1}x+a_{0}$ where $a_{n} ,...,a_{1} $ are the coefficients of the polynomial and $a_{0}$ is a constant, find the value of $a_{n} ,...,a_{0}$, and $a_{n}$ ≠ 0, if:
At any two points on the curve of P(x) with x-coordinates of $\alpha , \beta$, when a line is connected through those two points, the y-intercept of the line is
$$-\alpha \beta \sum_{k=2}^{n}\left ( \left ( k-1 \right ) \sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\alpha ^{n-r-k}\beta ^{r}\right )$$

I got this problem from my friend. He said he made it himself and I'm free to search it in the internet, and here I am. I have found the gradient of the line and the y-intercept in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but to equal it to the double sum is a little confusing to me.

The methods I used are from my high school knowedge only. I first let the line $f\left ( x \right )=mx+c
$. Gradient,$m= \frac{P\left ( \alpha  \right )-P\left ( \beta  \right )}{\alpha -\beta } $ then y-intercept,$c = \frac{\alpha P\left ( \beta \right )-\beta P\left (\alpha   \right )}{\alpha -\beta } $. Then I expand and equate c and the double sum, but I don't know how.

Comment: Try small values of $n$ perhaps to start with. Why isn't $c$ named $a_0$?

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first time posting anything about math here and don't know the correct math phrase and things. If it is too bad then I'll consider reposting it after the edits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have

\begin{equation}\sum _{r = 0}^{n-k} {{\alpha}}^{n-r-k} {{\beta}}^{r} = \frac{{{\alpha}}^{n-k+1}-{{\beta}}^{n-k+1}}{{\alpha}-{\beta}}\end{equation}

hence

\begin{equation}{-{\alpha}} {\beta} \sum _{k = 2}^{n} \left(k-1\right) \sum _{r = 0}^{n-k} {{\alpha}}^{n-r-k} {{\beta}}^{r} = \frac{{\alpha} P \left({\beta}\right)-{\beta} P \left({\alpha}\right)}{{\alpha}-{\beta}}\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}P \left({\alpha}\right) = \sum _{k = 2}^{n} \left(k-1\right) {{\alpha}}^{n-k+2} = \alpha^n + 2 \alpha^{n-1}+ 3\alpha^{n-2}+\ldots+(n-1)\alpha^2
\end{equation}

Comment: @ThereExistsACertainThing You are getting downvoted because you didn't include your own efforts to solve the problem in your question. I'm getting downvoted because I give you a hint instead of punishing you for your effrontery. Tolerance is not the most widespread quality in math.stackexchange ...

Comment: Damn is it always like this? I'm sorry.

Comment: Well I guess if you include your own efforts in the questions, you can avoid downvotes in the future. People think they have good reasons to act this way but it doesn't make these sites very friendly. My former PhD advisor says to enjoy science or do something else. I think the same.

Comment: I've added it now, is it enough?

Comment: @ThereExistsACertainThing I think there is an error in the question because when $\beta = \alpha$, the intercept should be $P(\alpha) - \alpha P'(\alpha)$ which has degree $n$ in $\alpha$, but the $Q(\alpha, \beta)$ that you gave has degree $n+2$ when $\beta = \alpha$.

Comment: Oh damn I really made a typo in the question. I'm soooo sorry. The first sum should be k=2 not 0. My bad. There should be no errors now.

Comment: My friends says almost!! But don't forget the $a_1$ term!

Comment: Ok one can add an arbitrary term $a_1 x$, it doesn't change the $y$-intercept. I didn't claim there was no other solution.